# Pull back a vector field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In Voisin's book *Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry, I*  Section 9.1.2, p.223, the author writes:

> Let $\phi:\mathcal X\to B$ be a family fo complex manifolds. The differential $\phi_*$ is a morphism of holomorphic vector bundles $T_{\mathcal X}\to \phi^*T_B$.

If my understanding is right, $\phi^*T_B$ is the space of pullbacks of vector fields in $T_B$. But is it always possible to pull back a vector field? As far as I know, differential forms can always be pulled back, but I never see anyone push forward a differential form. Similarly, we can often see push forward a vector at a point, but I'm not sure pull back a vector field is always possible. In Loring. Tu's book *an introduction to manifolds, 2nd edition*, p.196, the author writes:

> Unlike vector fields, which in general cannot be pushed forward under a smooth map, every covector field can be pulled back by a smooth map.

He even did not mention the pullback of a vector field, which, I guess, implies that pull back a vector field is generally impossible, then why did Voisin write $\phi^*T_B$ without hesitation? Or is the submersivity of $\phi$ guarantees the existence of $\phi^*T_B$ tacitly?

In summary, my question is:

Under which condition, can we pull back a vector field?

Comment: In general, given a map of manifolds $f \colon M \to N$, there are induced maps of vector bundles $$ T_M \to f^* T_N, \quad f^* \Omega^1_N \to \Omega^1_M,$$ obtained roughly speaking by putting together all the differentials of $f$ at the points of $M$ (and dualizing). A vector field is an element in $\Gamma(TM)$, and a covector field (1-form) is an element in $\Gamma(\Omega^1_M)$, maybe you are making some confusion here.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi, what's your definition of $f^*T_N$?

Comment: The standard one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_bundle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are **not** pulling back vector fields.

You are pulling back the vector bundle $T_B$ to be a bundle over $\mathcal{X}$. (See, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_bundle for a description.)

Notice that in general, the nomenclature "pushforward of a vector field" is imprecise. When the mapping is not bijective, "$\phi_*v$" does not define a vector field over the codomain: if $q$ is not in the image of $\phi$ then $\phi_*v$ is undefined, and if $\phi$ is not injective the same $q$ may be associated to two distinct values of $\phi_*v$.

Thinking in terms of the pullback tangent bundle solves both of these issues.

(The pullback of a differential form, on the other hand, is always precise, since functions must be well defined on its domain.)

Comment: Although the question seems a bit stupid now, the answer is excellent which solves the problem totally and clearly, Thx!